Why can’t Biden approve the deal to avert a shutdown?
Why can’t Biden approve the deal to avert a shutdown?
Why does it need to be approved by someone who’s not president yet?
Can’t Biden approve now while he’s still president?

Granted, for those in the know, passing these bills is not the job of the president, and esp. not of the president elect.  But given that the news is saturated with information about this being a Trump (and Musk) power play, someone unfamiliar with the US system could assume that it was something a POTUS needed to approve.  No need to be so hard on the Q, the answer given indicates clearly enough who is responsible for what.

Biden can’t approve the deal because it’s legislation, not an executive order, and has to be passed by Congress. It doesn’t legally need to be approved by Musk or Trump, but most of the Republican Representatives are scared of them and will vote accordingly.

For what it's worth, Biden probably approves of the deal. Just doesn't mean anything.

"Scared" seems like unnecessary commentary.  Why do you need to say it.  Why is it surprising that the majority of Republican Congresspeople support the Republican President elect? Do you say that the Democratic Congresspeople were "scared" into voting for Infrastructure Investment and Jobs Act by Biden (for example)?

@JamesK - I guess the supposition is that they are actually opposed to Trump's position, but support it out of fear that he will support a primary challenger to them or otherwise make their lives difficult.

Yes, Mike is implying that, and in doing so making this a "push" answer (it's an answer, but it's more about getting a little dig in against T)

@JamesK Given that it was a bipartisan measure until this week, ... what would your interpretation be why the deal is currently off the table? Maybe some other word that sounds more neutral like "convinced"?

Yeah, "scared" is just a cheap shot.  How can we expect questioners not to ask boring partisan push questions?  My interpretation is that the Republican congress party are strong supporters of Trump.  Not because of "fear" but because of "Republican"  They withdrew support for the bill because their President elect doesn't support it and they are in his party.  It would be more interesting, politically, if large numbers of republicans were willing to oppose their own leader.  Supporting your party is a non-story, really.

@JamesK It's kind of a fallacy to assume that just because polemics and partisanship often get in the way of the truth, that this would mean that neutrality and politeness have a relationship with the truth... The thing is, many republicans are not strong supporters of Trump (or at least pretend not to be), who have previously been outspoken critics of both him and his policies. But when push comes to shove they fall in line anyway. So what is it? Liars? Spineless? Opportunists? Scared? Is it a smoke screen? Partisan tactics? Strategical dishonesty? How do you wish to frame that as a positive?

I don't want it "framed" at all.  The answer to the question is simple "Biden can't approve legislation that hasn't been passed"  You don't need to get a jibe in a Trump.  It makes a perfectly good answer into a yet another partisan barb.  Why how does it improve the question? It really doesn't.  Look, in my partisan life, I'm pretty liberal.  I dislike all that Trumps republican party is and does. I find it incomprehensible that anyone could vote for such an obscene creature. But this question is not the place for me or anyone else to push this.

It may well be that they are indeed scared by Trump and Co. but we don't know for sure, so it would be better to use a neutral formulation leaving it open or to use a numeration where scared is one of several options. GOP representatives changed their opinion by the usual mechanism that are inherent to politics and especially the tactics that Trump uses typically including but not limited to scaring people. He did scare in the past, right?

I want questions that are genuine and answers that answer the question.  Not the endless stream of questions that are "How terrible is Trump/Biden/Hasina/Modi/Orban/Tómasdóttir... amiright"

@JamesK Fair enough I agree with that sentiment, but in that case it does actually seem to hinge upon Trump. That is technically the answer is correct that it's legislation not executive orders so it's legally  a matter of congress and not the president to begin with. But that's only half of the problem, the other part is that Trump effectively gutted a bipartisan bill, so in a sense those bills seem to need his "approval". That being said, a Trump/Musk approved bill also failed the vote today, despite a republican majority. So he seems to have de facto blocking but not passing power.

... It's obviously also possible that the republicans in the house would have rejected both bills anyway, without Trump interjection himself. Though he did e.g. with threats: "Any Republican that would be so stupid as to do this should, and will, be Primaried," Trump wrote on social media." https://www.reuters.com/world/us/us-house-speaker-defends-stopgap-spending-some-republicans-musk-balk-2024-12-18/ And it apparently worked to stop bipartisan efforts (whether they would have been successful is a different question). So it's hard to keep him outside of those question when he injects himself

Also it's "XYZ is terrible... amiright" that is a problem asking HOW terrible they actually are is a valid concern, though probably a "little" too broad and unspecific to make for a good question.

@JamesK How often do you see members of congress risk a government shutdown because a president elect and an unelected advisor says they don't like something? To me that says they are scared of upsetting him. There was no question about it being passed until Trump and Musk spoke against it which shows that it was their actions that was causing it issues.

I'm not arguing that point. I don't give a damn if they are "scared". I don't even care. It's just I don't like it when people use their answers to make cheap jibes at the "other side".  There is a massive problem of people using  politics.se to make points.  This question can be answered without having a dig at Trump, fun though that may be.

@JamesK You sure seem to be saying that they are not "scared" a lot for someone who doesn't care. The fact remains is that they changed their position on the budget bill after they got threatened by Tump/Musk which shows that it isn't just a matter of supporting Trump's wishes. The fact that Trump is having to threaten members of congress to get his way shows that he doesn't have their support and that they are only acting his way based on the fear of what he is threatening them with.

Given BBC:  This amounted to a stunning rebuke of the president-elect, who had enthusiastically endorsed the legislation and threatened to unseat any Republicans who opposed it. I don'tunderstand the big issue with "scared" as a formulation.  And especially not with Trump's past history of turfing out Republican opponents.

@JamesK The question asked "Why does it have to be approved by someone who isn't President yet?". So they're clearly asking why Trump's opinion matters, and that opens up the "because GOP Congressmen need to please Trump" can of worms. The same thing happened earlier this year when Trump shot down the bipartisan border bill when he was just a candidate.

@JamesK it isn’t a cheap jibe to correctly point out that Republicans changed their position in response to threats made by Trump and Musk.

As was mentioned in an answer by Mike Scott, Biden is unable to do anything until after Congress passes the budget. However it is clear that Republicans in the house are afraid of Trump and what he will do if they support the bipartisan budget bill.
There was no question of the budget passing until after Trump and Musk voiced opposition to it and threatened lawmakers if they supported it.
Trump threatens to primary Republicans who don’t support funding demands

President-elect Donald Trump abruptly rejected a bipartisan plan
Wednesday to prevent a Christmastime government shutdown, instead
telling House Speaker Mike Johnson and Republicans to essentially
renegotiate — days before federal funding runs out.
Trump warned that Republicans who support federal funding without a
debt ceiling increase would be primaried.

The fact is that Trump and his followers have been successfully primarying Republicans who don't do exactly what Trump wants and the Republican members of the house don't want to be the next to get primaried.
